# Не доступен ключ в массиве $_POST

Tags: php

Не доступен ключ в массиве $_POST

```
<?php if (isset($_post["password"]))
```

Comment: Поконкретнее можно?

Comment: И на русском языке

Comment: @Nosir Поправьте вопрос или его удалят.

Answer (score 3):

Переменные в РНР чувствительны к регистру

поэтому правильно будет `$_POST`